# Environment variable overrides command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, terraform

I set the `EC2_IP_ADDRESS` variable

```
$ export EC2_IP_ADDRESS="`docker run -it -v $PWD/infrastructure:/terraform -v $PWD/data:/data terraform sh -c "terraform init; terraform state show module.aws_ec2.aws_eip.aws_instance_eip" | grep public_ip | awk '{print $3}'`"
```

And then I'm trying to copy some files into the EC2 instance:

```
$ scp -i key.pem -r src/* ec2-user@$EC2_IP_ADDRESS:/home/ec2-user/src/
```

But the output is an error: **: nodename nor servname provided, or not known**

Output of `$ echo "scp -i key.pem -r src/* ec2-user@$EC2_IP_ADDRESS:/home/ec2-user/src/"`

```
:/home/ec2-user/src/c/* ec2-user@X.X.X.X
```

It seems that anything after the variable `EC2_IP_ADDRESS` goes to the beginning of the string, overriding the command.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try running the `echo "scp...` through `xxd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the variable contains `$'\r'` at the end. Remove it with

```
EC2_IP_ADDRESS=${EC2_IP_ADDRESS%$'\r'}
```